# Get all commits for a given file with LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

From a local repository, I want to get all commits that either created or changed a specific file. Until now our application handled this by putting the filename in the commit message and then searching for commit messages with that name when creating the history. I'd like to have a cleaner solution that doesn't involve commit messages, if possible.

This is what I tried so far:

```
private List<Commit> GetAllCommitsForFile(string repositoryPath, string filename)
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(repositoryPath))
    {
        List<LogEntry> logs = repo.Commits.QueryBy(Path.Combine(RepositoryPath, filename)).ToList(); 
        List<Commit> commits = new List<Commit>();

        foreach(LogEntry log in logs)
        {
            commits.Add(log.Commit);
        }

        return commits;
    }
}
```

The description of the QueryBy-method says:

> Returns the list of commits of the repository representing the history of a file beyond renames.

To me, that sounds like it's exactly what I want. Yet, when I pass only the filename, I get a KeyNotFoundException, and when I combine it with the repository path, I get an empty list.

Comment: _"when I pass only the filename, I get an exception"_ - and what does it tell you?

Comment: @CodeCaster Edited, sorry for being lazy.

Comment: And does it have a message? And what does your history look like, can you create a [mre]? See also https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1410

Comment: Well, the message says: "The given Key was not present in the directory", no new information here. As for the history: There are a couple of commits that each create one or two files. So for a reproduction you would commit a couple of files to a new repo and then run the above method on one of them...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar and found this post. Maybe this "just works" now due to library updates, but for what it's worth, the following similar code worked for me:

```
 var repoPath = @"C:\Users\whoever\Documents\git\SomeRepoName";
 var fileOffset = @"YouTube\subscriptions\subscriptions.json";
 var fileOffsetFwdSlash = fileOffset.Replace("\\", "/");
 using (var repo = new Repository(repoPath))
 {
     var logs = repo.Commits.QueryBy(fileOffsetFwdSlash).ToList();
     foreach (var log in logs)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine(log.Commit.Author.When);
     }
 }
```

I used the file's offset from the repository root, and I needed to replace backslashes with forward slashes. I got almost exactly the same output as from the command line

```
git log --follow -- YouTube/subscriptions/subscriptions.json
```

With the exception of the fact that the first commit affecting the file appeared in the command line output and not in LibGet2Sharp's output.

Comment: do you know how to get the 1st commit affecting the file?